# Is it possible to have nested node shapes on Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to have nested shapes on Graphviz?

I would like to have a diamond inside a square, like the image bellow:

[image: ER Associative entity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution:

```
subgraph cluster_1 {
    margin = 1;
    label  = "";
    associative_entity [shape = diamond, height = 1];
}
```

Comment: Note that works only for the default layout engine (dot).

Answer (score 0):

The [Msquare](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) shape might be close enough if your own solution doesn't work well for what you want.